# Updating Database with Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, ado.net

I can add to, and remove from a Database table with Linq to Entities. However the following code will not update the database. (There are no exceptions, or anything - it just doesn't update.):

```
        // Change box qty
        var pnumber = Request.Form["PartNumber"];
        var oid = Session["OOID"];
        var uid = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
        var newqty = Request.Form["Quantity"];
        var c = (from item in database.Carts
                           where item.UserId == 
                           uid && item.PartNumber == 
                           pnumber && item.OrderId == (string)oid
                           select item.Boxes).FirstOrDefault();
        c = newqty.AsInt();
        database.SaveChanges();
        Response.Redirect("~/Protected/Account/Shopping/Cart");
```

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong, or how to resolve this? I've searched Stack Overflow and tried various samples provided in the Answers, and also on Google, but they're all pretty much the same, and haven't helped.

Comment: You need to grab the whole entity and update it, not just a specific field.  Once you've grabbed the field, you just have a `int` variable completely disconnected from the database, stored in `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's @Xander's answer using Lambda's

```
var newqty = Request.Form["Quantity"]; 
var c = database.Carts.Where(x => x.UserId == 
           uid && x.PartNumber == 
           pnumber && x.OrderId == (string)oid).FirstOrDefault();
c.Boxes = newqty.AsInt();
database.SaveChanges();
```

I know you said you got an error with his, this is more for you educational purposes :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not sure why, but this exact same code (that you provided, and which I had originally tried a few days ago) wasn't working, but it did today. Strange, but nice :)

Answer (score 5):

You basically need to retrieve the entity (record) itself and not just the property (column) to be able to update it through EF:

```
var newqty = Request.Form["Quantity"]; 
var c = (from item in database.Carts
           where item.UserId == 
           uid && item.PartNumber == 
           pnumber && item.OrderId == (string)oid
           select item).FirstOrDefault();
c.Boxes = newqty.AsInt();
database.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Oh, I tried that one, too (originally) - I'll provide you with exception details.

Comment: Hmm, strange. It's not throwing an exception today. But it still won't update. I think the problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: I've triple-checked everything. From the cart page that passes (as query string) data to change to the editquantity page, to the code that actually "updates" the database. Everything is how it should be. I don't get it.

Comment: @EvilCokeMachine This shouldn't have any effect in your situation, but just to be certain, have you tried setting the entity's state to modified?  Like this: `database.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(c, EntityState.Modified);`

Comment: @Xander - I wasn't aware of that, thanks. I just tried it, and it gave the following exception: `ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'System.Int32'`

Comment: @EvilCokeMachine can you run sql profiler to see what .net is sending up?

Comment: Sure, i'm on it now, won't be a sec

Comment: I've had to use an alternative, as I can't get SQL Profiler working on this comp. Alt: http://anjlab.com/en/projects/opensource/sqlprofiler